# Does JavaScript create issues when we implement master pages

Tags: javascript, asp.net, master-pages

Does JavaScript create an issue when we implement master pages?

It seems to me that it is quite tough to maintain and implement JavaScript on an application where we have used master pages. Is there any shortcut or the other way round to it?

Comment: Now if I use .js file to implement javascript wouldn't it become very difficult to manage the various pages and controls that might be using it. Further say i have 2 .js files then the master page would always pose a issue as the 2 different content pages might require different .js but their master page could be same. So is it really worthy to use master pages if we r going to use javascript extensively in our application

Comment: Hi Pandiya,
Well finding clientId's is not an issue as it can be resolved by getting the ClientID property of that particular control, which is generated at runtime and is avaliable for us. But how to use it to our benefit if we are using javascript and master pages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no javascript issues when using master pages in asp.net unless you create some. ;)

While writing javascript you should see the final html generated when the page is processed and work on that html rather than thinking in terms of master page or content pages. You can put your common javascript functions in the master page so that it can be accessed in all the content pages. Also I would recommend putting all your javascript in an external file and including it in the master page. This is a good practice.

If you are facing some issues you can post the specific problem and we can try and solve them.

All the best...

Answer (score 3):

Hai HotTester,

The Major issue would be finding **ClientId's** of controls used in your application.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with finding of ClientID's in MasterPages in ASP.Net 3.5... As the content page has its own head tag unlike ASP.Net 2.0